# tcolorbox wrong newtcolorbox formatting

Tags: tcolorbox, page-breaking

I'm struggling with the problem of proper wrapping of the environment which I am use in twocolumn page layout - with book class scrbook. I am using the [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to define fancy boxes. As you can see in my code, I have two color-boxes. One for note called `tcnote` and other one box for definition (as is usual in a math textbook).

Unfortunately, the compilation result depends on how much text is on the page. For example if I add more dummy text, then the result is terrible as you can see on the figure below. You can play with my code by commenting/uncomenting the line `\lipsum[1][2]  % dummy text ON/OF`

- Outside the tcnote environment, the equation in green box will print as expected.
- Inside the tcnote environment the equation is printed outside the green box which is wrong.
- The tcnote environment is split over several pages, although one page should be enough.

[image]

**MNWE:**

```
  \documentclass[fontsize=10pt,twocolumn]{scrbook}
  
  \usepackage{lipsum}  
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
    \newcommand\abs[1]{\ensuremath{\lvert#1\rvert}}

\newtcolorbox{tcnote}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw, % better frame drawing
  enforce breakable,         % breakable,
  borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{red}, % straight vertical line at the left edge
  sharp corners, % No rounded corners
  boxrule=0pt, % no real frame,
  coltitle={red!25!black},  % Black colour for title
  colback={yellow!30},
  attach title to upper, % Move the title into the box
  right=10pt,
  compress page,
  enhanced,
  #1
}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{fyzdef}{DEF}{%
  colback=green!5!white,
  colframe=green!75!black,
  fonttitle=\itshape,        % \bfseries,
  enforce breakable,         % breakable,
  compress page,
  enhanced,
}{fyz}  


\begin{document}
  \section{Section}
    \lipsum[5]
    \lipsum[5]
    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[1][2]
    % \lipsum[1][2]  % dummy text ON/OF

    \begin{fyzdef}{Kronecker}{def016}
      \begin{equation}           
        \delta_{ij} = 
        \begin{cases} 
            1  & \text{for } i = j     \\
            0  & \text{for } i \neq j.
        \end{cases}
      \end{equation}
    \end{fyzdef}

    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{tcnote}    
      \lipsum[1]
      
      \begin{fyzdef}{Einstein sume rule}{def015}
        \lipsum[1][3]
        \begin{equation*}
          a'_i = \sum^3_{j=1} = \alpha_{ij}a_j.            
        \end{equation*}
        text
        \begin{equation}
          a_ia_i = a_1a_1 + a_2a_2 + a_3a_3 = \abs{a}^2 = a^2.    % (2.1)       
        \end{equation}
      \end{fyzdef}

      \lipsum[1][2]

      \begin{fyzdef}{Kronecker}{def016}
        \begin{equation}           
          \delta_{ij} = 
          \begin{cases} 
              1  & \text{for } i = j     \\
              0  & \text{for } i \neq j.
          \end{cases}
        \end{equation}
      \end{fyzdef}

      \lipsum[1][2]
      \begin{equation}
        a'_i = α_{ij} a_j         
      \end{equation}
      \lipsum[1][2]
      \begin{equation}
        α_{ik} α_{ij} = δ_{kj},    
      \end{equation}
      \lipsum[1]

    \end{tcnote}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you replace `enforce breakable` with `breakable` it's fine. The tcolorbox [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) says `enforce breakable` "... will usually give a mess
of shattered boxes. You are advised to not use this option"

Answer (score 0):

According to mbert's post the solution is to replace `enforce breakable` with simple switch `breakable`.

The [tcolorbox](https://mirror.physik.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) documentation says that switch `enforce breakable` has side effect when it is used for breakable box inside a breakable box. In that case it will usually give a mess.